# PayPal mpl Android, initialization issue with ENV_SANDBOX

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am implementing an Adaptive Payment using delayed chained payment.
To do that, I simply run the following steps:

1) From server side I use https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Preapproval the get a preapproval key

2) From client side I use mpl for Android to let the user approve the key

3) From server side I create payments using the preapproval key, approved by the user

The problem is that I want to use mpl in the Sandbox environment to test everything but, when I initialize the PayPal library (in Android) I get the following error in onActivityResult:

"APPLICATION NOT AUTHORIZED", ERROR CODE: -1

This is the code:

```
PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();
if (pp == null) {
         pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(this, "APP-80W284485P519543T", PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);
         pp.setLanguage("en_US");
         pp.setFeesPayer(PayPal.FEEPAYER_SECONDARYONLY);
         pp.setShippingEnabled(true);
         pp.setDynamicAmountCalculationEnabled(false);
         boolean isAppInit = pp.isLibraryInitialized();
}
pp.setPreapprovalKey("PA-64N62546XG272001B");

Intent preapproveIntent = pp.preapprove(preapproval, Taskhunters.getContext());
startActivityForResult(preapproveIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Instead if I use the environment PayPal.ENV_NONE, the application is properly initialized but I need to test it in the Sandbox environment because otherwise the preapproval key is not set as "approved" and I can't complete the payment flow.

I have three sandbox accounts properly created and all the API calls I make from the server are perfectly working.

So the question is:
HOW I CAN GET THE MPL WORKING WITH THE SANDBOX ENVIRONMENT???

For those who will suggest to use the embedded flow, I have already tried it but the usability is awful.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem.
MPL requires the permission READ_PHONE_STATE which became a "dangerous permission" from Android 6. 
To make MPL working again, just ask to the user to grant that permission before using the library.

Comment: Are you testing on 6.0?

Comment: is it working fine on 6.0 now? I am facing issue with 5.1

Comment: Yes, the problem I had was related to the missing permission. Now that I ask for it, everything is working fine.